# Как сделать пользовательский начальный индекс массива?

Tags: c#, массивы, index

К примеру мне нужно чтоб первый элемент массива имел индекс 3 а не 0

Comment: Эт зачем вам такие извращения?

Comment: Такое задание от преподавателя )

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: В массиве вряд ли, а вот в коллекции можно. Задайте смещение индекса в индексаторе коллекции.  Т.е. наследуетесь, к примеру от List<T>, и замещаете индексатор.

Comment: Небось преподаватель тоже тут сидит)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для создания массива, у которого начальный индекс не 0, нужно воспользоваться методом [Array.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x836773a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Одна из перегрузок данного метода, позволяет задать *lowerBound* (начальный индекс)

Пример создания массива из 10 целых чисел, со стартовым индексом 3 может выглядеть так:

```
var arr = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), new[] { 10 }, new[] { 3 });
```

Очевидная проблема с таким массивом - с ним может быть не так удобно работать, как с *zero-based*.

Как минимум для заполнения массива, вместо обращения по индексу необходимо использовать [метод *SetValue*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kk3bwkb0(v=vs.110).aspx), по аналогии, для получения значения необходимо использовать [метод *GetValue*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6swd8604(v=vs.110).aspx).

Но его все еще можно использовать вместе с [оператором foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx)

```
foreach (var item in arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

---

Пример заполнения такого массива:

```
    for (int i = arr.GetLowerBound(0); i <= arr.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        arr.SetValue(i % 3, i);
    }
```

В примере используются функции [GetUpperBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.array.getupperbound(v=vs.110).aspx) и [GetLowerBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.array.getlowerbound(v=vs.110).aspx) возвращающие соответственно начальный и конечный индексы для выбранного измерения (для одномерного массива - 0). Так как эти функции возвращают допустимые индексы, условие в цикле *включает* верхнюю границу.

Альтернативным методом заполнения может являться [метод Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/k4yx47a1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Например:

```
Array.Copy(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 }, arr, 10);
```

При этом: `arr[3] == 1`, `arr[4] == 2` и т.д.

Answer (score 3):

Это возможно через перегрузки [Array.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx)

Массив из 5 элементов, начальный индекс - 2:

```
Array arrayObject = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), new int[] { 5 }, new int[] { 2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что в С# нет возможности перегрузить оператор `[]`. Зато есть возможность определить свой индексатор.

Пример определения пользовательского индексатора:

```
 class MyArr
    {
        int[] arr;
        public int Length;

        public MyArr(int Size)
        {
            arr = new int[Size];
            Length = Size;
        }

        public int this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return arr[index];
            }

            set
            {
                arr[index] = value;
            }
        }


    }
```