# Как сделать перебор по индексам многомерного массива в C#?

Tags: c#, массивы

Допустим перебор массива массивов можно сделать так:

```
int[][] a2 = new int[][]{ new int[]{ 1, 2 }, new int[] { 2, 3 }, new int[] { 3, 4 } };
for (int i = 0; i < a2.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < a2[i].Length; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a2[i][j]);
    }
}
```

А как подобное организовать для двумерного массива?

```
int[,] a1 = { { 1, 2 }, { 2, 3 }, { 3, 4 } };
for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < ????; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a1[i,j]);
    }
}
```

Что нужно поставить на месте "????"

Comment: [связанный вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/639796/186999)

Answer (score 5):

> [Array.GetLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.array.getlength(v=vs.110).aspx): Возвращает 32-разрядное целое число, представляющее
>   количество элементов в заданном измерении массива

```
int[,] a1 = { { 1, 2 }, { 2, 3 }, { 3, 4 } };
for (int i = 0; i < a1.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < a1.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a1[i,j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

для получения индекса последнего элемента в определенном измерении массива используется метод GetUpperBound

```
int[,] a1 = { { 1, 2 }, { 2, 3 }, { 3, 4 } };
for (int i = 0; i <= a1.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
      for (int j = 0; j <= a1.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(a1[i,j]);
      }
 }
```

Comment: _GetUpperBound_ - не возвращает количество элементов, он возвращает _максимальный допустимый индекс_

Comment: да действительно, поправил